# TAcroPDF Focusing Issue

Tags: delphi, setfocus

I wish to iterate of a folder of pdf files containing voucher images. I am viewing each file in a TAcroPDF component. The uses can seer the amount written on the voucher and can enter this amount into a textbox. On pressing the ENTER key the next voucher is displayed and I wish to automatically refocus on the textBox.  For some reason the Form is not passing focus to the TEdit component even though ActiveControl is edtAmount.

I have triedt edtAmout.SerFocus after the ShowImage function. I have tried PostMessage and edtAnount.Perform. I wveb have an OnIdle Handler with this code

```
  if not edtAmount.Focused then
    PostMessage(Handle, um_AmountFocus,0,0);
```

All hadlers are being processed. What I am missing is why the TAcroPDF seems to hog the focus.

I can manually double click into the TEdit but I need a less user-intensive solutrion

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delayed response. One thing that I found that works is to use a TTimer; enable the Timer after you call LoadFile, and in the Timer event set the focus to your edtAmount. A timer delay of 500 milliseconds seems to work in my case. Disable the timer after the SetFocus call.

Answer (score 0):

Using the LoadFile method caused focus issues

```
  AcroPDF1.LoadFile(PDFFileName); //was the source of the focusing problem
```

use

```
 AcroPDF1.src:=PDFFileName;
```

instead.